# Synchronize content of website on NLB servers

Tags: iis, load-balancing, fileshare, nlb

what would be the best way to have a website that is hosted on two distinct IIS servers which are load-balanced using Microsoft's NLB to sync the files that could be uploaded from the website's users?

Example: Site on server A is the one User A is visiting. User A goes to a page that allows him to uplad an image to the web site, which will then be displayed.
Now, User B goes to the same site and access the page where images are displayed but he's load balanced to Server B. User B doesn't see the image uploaded by User A because no file has been uploaded to server B.
Right now, we're using Robocopy but I find this solution not very practical as we need the files to be available very fast without having to rely on a scripted tool that a) might fail for lots of reasons, b) storage containing twice the files isn't very acceptable since a lot of space will be needed and we do not want to have to buy storage units twice for one file version, it just doesn't make sense.

So, what are your suggestions, community? :)

Answer (score 0):

We've dealt with this issue by setting up a UNC file share (e.g. \fileserver\shared\content) and then using that to hold the content that needs to be shared between the NLB nodes.  A single point of failure is avoided by have the share hosted on a clustered file server.